# How to enter the env cmd mode?

Tags: windows, cmd

**I use window10 system,I see some people's cmd is like this:**

[image]

**There is a env in front of it.**
**But my cmd does not have env.**

**My cmd:**
[image]
**How can I switch to this env mode?**

Comment: adapt your [prompt](https://ss64.com/nt/prompt.html).

Comment: If you just want your prompt string to start with '(env)' you can do `prompt (env) $P$G` but I suspect that's not what you're asking. You refer to "the env cmd mode". There is no such thing. It may be something customized your colleagues have set up specifically on their machines; you'll have to ask them about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I understand the "env" mode,in fact,I can use virtualenv's command

> activate

to do it.
For example:

> E:\python_virtualenv>cd E:\python_virtualenv\mycode\Scripts
>
> E:\python_virtualenv\mycode\Scripts>activate
>
> (mycode) E:\python_virtualenv\mycode\Scripts>echo
>   %GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS%
>   D:\analyze_sentiment\MyFirstProject-bbe4f7bccb98.json

In fact ,the "mycode" is "env".